# Why was question 11726 about making people respect your wishes reopened?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[How can you make someone to respect your wishes?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/11726/1599)

I close-voted that this morning as a duplicate of [How to make my mom respect my wish of not being photographed?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/7245/how-to-make-my-mom-respect-my-wish-of-not-being-photographed)

Basically, the OP had a problem with people photographing them, it included a rant on a past occurence, some very opinion based flame-bait, an enormous lack of detail (lacking a cultural background, info on the people that are taking these pictures, relation to the 'bullies', for example), it's about making people do something, which is considered a bad fit for IPS since you can't make people do stuff.

Trying to be helpful and leave the OP with at least some kind of answer to their question, I found the duplicate, which is, I agree, about dealing with a parent. The advice over there seems generic enough though that it might be relevant for future situations the OP finds themselves in too *since they haven't specified the persons they're dealing with*. I could also have closed it as too broad, unclear what you're asking, primarily opinion based or off-topic, it's just about what flaw you want to emphasize here.

I get it that some people might have disagreed with it being a duplicate, but it's up to the OP of a question to decide and describe how their question is different from the duplicate and to provide enough context. If the close-reason 
was wrong, why not take it to meta, but leave the question closed to be improved?

What makes this question good enough to be reopened without first editing it into shape?

Comment: I am not sure if questions about getting people to do (or in this case stop doing) something are off topic. Is there a meta or help page about this? I can list over 30 highly voted questions all about making someone stop doing something.

Comment: Three recent examples: [Make someone stop flirting +51](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/4728/convince-somebody-to-stop-flirting-with-me), [Make someone respect smoking beliefs +22](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/7154/how-can-i-get-my-sister-to-stop-asking-me-to-help-her-smoke), [Make people stop touching me without having to freak out +53](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/9016/how-to-stop-people-from-touching-me-without-having-to-freak-out-at-them)

Answer (score 5):

I voted to reopen because I felt there was sufficient detail to distinguish it from the "duplicate" and because it appeared to have answered the questions in the comments.

The issues identified in comments were:

> **OP never mentioned what kind of people they're struggling with now, only that something happened in the past.**

Question now says OP is in high school dealing with classmates.

> **It's not clear to me what was already tried, why that didn't work.**

Question says:

> I tried to tell them "enough!!" but they don't listen

and:

> I have tried saying “stop doing this” but some people are stubborn.

and gives an example of a time they were filmed without permission.

> **What kind of people are we dealing with? What kind of culture?**

High schoolers in Bucharest.

> **How often is OP expected to be in a photo? Are we talking photo's taken at random moments or family requesting they be present in the photograph they're planning to send grandma?**

The example in the original revision was photos taken by classmates during a lunch break and posted online without OP's consent. So: random moments and not family.

> **Is it correct to say the people taking the pictures are bullies?**

OP describes them as "jerks who don’t respect people’s wishes" so it is at least clear that they are not being respectful and friendly, which was good enough to answer my question.